# Reading key-value from registry

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am reading a key-value from registry.It returns a javascript object as shown below,

[image: pic]

I am not able to access the value.

```
I tried to print the value as 
path="HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment";
console .log(result.path.values.USERNAME);//prints undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
result[path].values.USERNAME // array syntax
```

In JavaScript it's not useful to use a variable as the Object's property name when you use the "regular object syntax", it will return undefined (if it doesn't have a property with the exact name of your variable):

```js
const obj = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

let prop = 'key1'

// this returns undefined,
// as obj doesn't have a prop1 property
console.log('obj.prop:', obj.prop)

// this display value1, because an Object
// is an Array (under the hood), so you can
// call it's keys in an array syntax
console.log('obj[prop]:', obj[prop])

// if the prop variable gets a new value, then
// it will return a value from obj according to
// prop's new value

prop = 'key2'
console.log('prop = \'key2\':', obj[prop])

// you can use the array syntax for listing out
// the property values of an Object:
for (let key in obj) {
  console.log('iteration ' + key + ':', obj[key])
}
```

Comment: I want to access the USERNAME variable only

Comment: Instead of USERNAME:[Object], I want to print the value of USERNAME

Comment: I modified my answer (just typing from phone) - it should give you the USERNAME value

Comment: What modification did you do?

Comment: Sorry - misunderstood your comment

Comment: What’s inside USERNAME? It seems that USERNAME is an object, so it has key-value inside

Comment: This is a dupe question, further, you didn't explain anything.

Comment: USERNAME is inturn an object but I can the value of it now